# Get next 100 records in suggest API azure search

Tags: jquery, azure-cognitive-search, search-suggestion

```
var suggest = function(request, response) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: suggestUri,
         dataType: "json",
         headers: {
             "api-key": "{{ searchServiceApiKey }}",
             "Content-Type": "application/json"
         },
         data: JSON.stringify({
             top: {{maxtopvalue}},
             select: "articlepublicnumber,Id,title,mrc_brandmultiselectstring",
             filter: "(statuscode eq 7 and statecode eq 3 and mrc_internalexternal eq '171700000')",
             suggesterName: "{{ searchSuggestorName }}",
             search: request.term,
             highlightPreTag: highlightPreTag,
             highlightPostTag: highlightPostTag
         }),
         open: function(event, ui) {
             $(".ui-autocomplete").hide();
         },
         success: function(data) {
             var autosuggestDataToDisplay=[];
             var result="";
             if (data.value && data.value.length > 0) {
                    for(i=0;i<data.value.length;i++)
                    {
                        var text=data.value[i]["@search.text"];
                        var brand=data.value[i].mrc_brandmultiselectstring;
                        if(text.length>0)
                        {
                           for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
                           {
                           if(text.toLowerCase().indexOf("KA")!=-1 && brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[j])!=-1)
                           { 
                                return '<a class="underline" title="' +  data.value[i]["articlepublicnumber"] + ' - ' + data.value[i]["title"] +
                                     '" href="/knowledgebase/article/' + data.value[i]["articlepublicnumber"] + '/en-us?highlight=' + data.value[i]["title"] + '" >'
                                    +  data.value[i]["articlepublicnumber"] + ' - ' + data.value[i]["title"] + '</a>';

                           }
                           else if(brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[j])!=-1){
                                result=result+","+text;
                                if(autosuggestDataToDisplay.indexOf(text.toLowerCase())===-1){
                                    autosuggestDataToDisplay.push(text);
                                 }                
                              }
                            }
                          }
                      }
             }
             if(result!=null)
             {
                response(autosuggestDataToDisplay.slice(0,10));
             }
         },
         error: function (data){
          console.log("error:"+data);
        }
     });
};
```

Comment: In the response from the API will be a `ContinuationToken` property. Include that in the following request to get the next N records in the dataset

Comment: Getting top 100 records in suggest api.After getting data some condition checks happens in success function.If I get zero results after condition checks then I need to get next 100 records and so on